# Trying to use `unmountComponentAtNode` from react-dom and I get errpor `main.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) `

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I was trying to remove an element from the DOM and tried using `unmountComponentAtNode` because I was still registering click events some how.
However, when I try to run

```
handleClickOutside= async () =>{
    console.log('the click is  outside');
    this.myRef = null;
    var element = await document.getElementsByClassName('RequestDropDown_container');
    if (element.length == 0) {
        return
    }

    element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
    unmountComponentAtNode(element[0]);       //error is happening here
  }
```

I get the following error in the console

```
main.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #40; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=40 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at t.unmountComponentAtNode (VM4083 main.js:36)
    at ba.<anonymous> (VM4083 main.js:52)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at n (VM4083 main.js:1)
    at s (VM4083 main.js:1)
```

is there anything I should do differently

Comment: How are you cleaning up your effects/listeners in the components adding them?

Comment: `componentWillMount() {

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick, false);

  }

  componentWillUnMount() {

    document.removeEventListener("mousedown'" this.handleClick, false);

  }

  handleClick= (e)=> {

      if(this.myRef.contains(e.target)) {
          console.log('you clicked inside')
          return;
      }

      this.handleClickOutside()

  }`
 @DrewReese

Comment: By any chance are you also passing this `handleClick` callback to any children components?

Comment: no, only using it in that component @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

Did you click the link in that error message?

> main.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #40; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=40 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

It says:

> unmountComponentAtNode(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Explain:

```
// First you remove the `element[0]` DOM node,
element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);

// then you tell ReactDOM to unmount component at node `element[0]`
unmountComponentAtNode(element[0]);
// which is already removed from DOM tree
// thus you get an error
```

Solution, simply remove this line:

```
element[0].parentNode.removeChild(element[0]);
```

Comment: I did try that and it works, The issue is that I am still triggering event listeners on that component after running unmountComponentAtNode(element[0]); @hackape